# How to capture finger movement direction in android phone?

Tags: android

I want to capture the finger movement direction on Android touch phone. If a user slides his finger in up/down/left/right direction, I want to capture this direction. How can I find this? Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Implement onTouchEvent(), and calculate dx and dy by where the user presses down and lifts up. You can use these values to figure out the direction of the move.

```
float x1, x2, y1, y2, dx, dy;
String direction;
switch(event.getAction()) {
    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        x1 = event.getX();
        y1 = event.getY();
        break;

    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP): {
        x2 = event.getX();
        y2 = event.getY();
        dx = x2-x1;
        dy = y2-y1;

        // Use dx and dy to determine the direction of the move
        if(Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
            if(dx>0)
              direction = "right";
            else
              direction = "left";
        } else {
            if(dy>0)
              direction = "down";
            else
              direction = "up";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer but I found some typos and had to bring some of those variables to a higher scope to make them mutable from inside the switch.

Comment: For the second switch case I used ACTION_MOVE instead of ACTION_UP because in a ViewPager swipe gets invoked without ACTION_UP. I have a ScrollView w/ vertical orientation held by a ViewGroup and that's a ViewPager page. Swipe on ScrollView does change page instead of not responding.
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: float dx = event.getX() - x1;
                        float dy = event.getY() - y1;if (Math.abs(dx) <= Math.abs(dy)) {//vertical scroll
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
 } else {v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);} break;

Comment: ScrollView w/ vertical orientation nested within another ScrollView, held by  a ViewGroup I meant.

Comment: this one works well if the user lift his/her finger and move the finger, how to handle the case when the user changing direction without lifting the finger?

Comment: how to handle when dx or dy will 0?

Comment: @vishalpatel right now it would default to "left" and "up" but you could add an "else if" case for "center"

Answer (score 13):

Your best bet would be to deal with the MotionEvent's you get from a View.OnTouchListener() callback.  The motion events keep track of how you are currently interacting with the View by its action property.

I would imagine you can calculate which direction someone slides their finger by examining the action property of the MotionEvents and the x/y values of where the motion event took place.

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            oldX= event.getX();
            oldY= event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int newX = motionEvent.getX();
            int newY = motionEvent.getY();

            int deltaX = oldX - newX;
            int deltaY = oldY - newY;

            if(Math.abs(deltaY)>Math.abs(deltaX))
              //Motion in Y direction.
            else
              // Motion in X direction.
            break;
         }
```

There are lots of other method available on the MotionEvent object for use as well:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: the bottom check should be `if(Math.abs(deltaY)>Math.abs(deltaX))`

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of having bunch of variables better to use [VelocityTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker)

Here is modified example from [Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement#velocity)

```
private var mVelocityTracker: VelocityTracker? = null

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

    when (event.actionMasked) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
            mVelocityTracker?.clear()
            // If necessary retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the
            // velocity of a motion.
            mVelocityTracker = mVelocityTracker ?: VelocityTracker.obtain()
            // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
            mVelocityTracker?.addMovement(event)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            mVelocityTracker?.run {
                val pointerId: Int = event.getPointerId(event.actionIndex)
                addMovement(event)
                // When you want to determine the velocity, call
                // computeCurrentVelocity(). Then call getXVelocity()
                // and getYVelocity() to retrieve the velocity for each pointer ID.
                computeCurrentVelocity(1000)

                val xVelocity = getXVelocity(pointerId)
                val yVelocity = getYVelocity(pointerId)

                if (abs(xVelocity) > abs(yVelocity))
                    if (xVelocity > 0)
                        // right
                    else
                        // left 
                else
                    if (yVelocity > 0)
                       // down
                    else
                       // up
            }
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
            // Return a VelocityTracker object back to be re-used by others.
            mVelocityTracker?.recycle()
            mVelocityTracker = null
        }
    }
    return true
}
```