# how to add a banner slide show to an android app

Tags: android

I want to add an image slideshow in my android app just like flipkart android app. There will be three image. At first it will show first image. When someone touch move horizontally, it will show next one.

I am at beginner level of android. Dont know how to achieve this. Need some help.

Thank.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //addListenerOnButton();
    //changeOnTouch();
}

public void changeOnTouch() {
    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                            .getLayoutParams();
              switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                     int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                     if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                     }
                     if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                     }

                     layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                     layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                     img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                     break;
              default:
                     break;
              }
              return true;
        }
 });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While SO community is a collection of individuals willing to help, your questions shows small research effort. Please get an understanding with some online tutorials, and then if you have a specific problem doing some specific thing, we are happy to help.

Comment: How would we know? Please post some code illustrating the initial steps you have taken. Then explain where you are stuck.

Comment: All i want to know that which component like imageswitcher or viewflipper should be used for the slideshow. here is my code.ok. my fault.. Sorry to post it here... I need some help that's y i post it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I Created to do what you asked for using `ViewFlipper`

1) create a folder called `anim` in your `res` folder and save the following xml files in it. These are the animation files you will use to manage the view transition. I don't remember the source of them.

a) enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="100%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

b) exit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="-100%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

c) pop_enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="-100%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

d) pop_exite.xml

```
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="100%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

2) The next two animation files are used to indicate no more views available in the flipping direction. Save them in `anim` folder too.

a) no_next.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="-5%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
               android:duration="100"/>
   <translate
                android:startOffset="100"
               android:fromXDelta="-5%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
               android:duration="100"/>
</set>
```

b) no_previous.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
               android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="5%"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
               android:duration="100"/>
   <translate
                android:startOffset="100"
               android:fromXDelta="5%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
               android:duration="100"/>
</set>
```

If you want to change the way animation is played, check this: [Tween Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween)

3) Add this to your layout where you want your slide show to appear:

```
<!-- layout before your slide show -->
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_flip1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription=""
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_flip2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription=""
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_view_flip3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription=""
                    android:src="@drawable/image3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
<!-- rest of your layout -->
```

4) Add this method to your class, it will manage view transition:

```
ViewFlipper flipper;
private static Handler handler = new Handler(); 
public void slideFipper(final String direction){
    final Animation no_next = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.no_next);
    final Animation no_previuos = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.no_previous);
      handler.post(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
            int currentView = flipper.getDisplayedChild();
            if (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                //left
                if (currentView < 2) {
                    flipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.enter);
                    flipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.exit);
                    flipper.showNext();
                } else {
                    flipper.startAnimation(no_next);
                }
            } else {
                //right
                if (currentView > 0) {
                    flipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.pop_enter);
                    flipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.pop_exit);
                    flipper.showPrevious();
                } else {
                    flipper.startAnimation(no_previuos);
                }
            }
          }
      }); 
}
```

5) Add this to your OnCreate method. We will find the flipper view and add to it TouchListener. I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151831/1709850) to get the touch direction.

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        flipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            float x1 = 0, x2, y1 = 0, y2, dx, dy;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                String direction;
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                        x1 = event.getX();
                        y1 = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP): {
                        x2 = event.getX();
                        y2 = event.getY();
                        dx = x2-x1;
                        dy = y2-y1;
                         // Use dx and dy to determine the direction
                        if(Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
                            if(dx>0)  {
                                direction = "right";
                            } else {
                                direction = "left";
                            }
                            slideFipper(direction);
                        } else {
                            if(dy>0) direction = "down";
                            else direction = "up";
                        }
                    }
                }
                v.performClick(); 
                return true;
            }
        });
```